# ggplot2 scale_y_continous sometimes makes graph not visible

Tags: r, ggplot2, limits

When creating a density plot using ggplot, I find that sometimes the curve would disappear when I set limits using scale_y_continuous.  I am hoping for an explanation.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
n=20  #number of simulations runs
X=data.frame(v=runif(n,.5,1))

#X %>% filter(X<20) %>% ggplot(aes(v))+geom_density()
p=X  %>% ggplot(aes(v))+geom_density()
p1=p+scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,3.2))
p2=p+scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.2,3.2))
p3=p+scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-0.2,3.2))

grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,ncol=3)
```

Here is the figure  created:

[image]

Note that for the middle image, the curve is not visible.

Comment: that's the behaviour of xlim/ylim arguments, to remove the points from the data therefore the density (which is actually a kind of contour plot) cannot be displayed anymore. If you're looking only to zoom in/out of the plot, use coord_cartesian

Comment: This is a duplicate. Does anyone have the "canonical" dupe to link to for this?